# Getting Python to print to the command line (the output of the graphviz command gvpr)

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to get Python to run this command, which runs fine from my command prompt:

```
ccomps -x rel_graph.dot | gvpr -c "N[nNodes($G)<5]{delete(0,$)}" | dot | gvpack | sfdp -Goverlap=prism | gvmap -e | gvpr "BEGIN{int m,w,e = 0} N[fontcolor=='blue']{m += 1} N[fontcolor=='green']{e += 1} N[fontcolor=='red']{w += 1} END{print(m); print(w); print(e);}"
```

In Python, I'm using:

```
temp = subprocess.Popen("""ccomps -x rel_graph.dot | gvpr -c \
    "N[nNodes($G)<5]{delete(0,$)}" | dot | gvpack | sfdp -Goverlap=prism \
    | gvmap -e | gvpr 'BEGIN{int m,w,e = 0} \
    N[fontcolor=="blue"]{m += 1} \
    N[fontcolor=="green"]{e += 1} \
    N[fontcolor=="red"]{w += 1} \
    END{print(m); print(w); print(e);}'
    """, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

...and then read/print lines from temp. The issue is that Python doesn't print the three last print statements (all are integers) to standard output, or at least I wasn't able to find it. The rest of the gvpr program works fine from Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the stdout \ stderr to files likes this -

```
from subprocess import Popen
std_out_file = "/tmp/stdout.log"
std_err_file = "/tmp/stderr.log"
command_to_execute = "<your-command>"
with open(std_out_file, "wb") as out, open(std_err_file, "wb") as err:
        p = Popen(command_to_execute, shell=True, cwd=<folder>, stdout=out, stderr=err)
p.communicate()
```

Then you read the stdout \ stderr from the files, for example:

```
f = open(std_out_file, "r")
stdout = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

You can check the return code of the command, to check if you also need to print the stderr like this -

```
if p.returncode == 0:
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, the expected standard program output (~250 lines) goes to std_err rather than std_out for some reason, but it's still missing the last few print commands.

Answer (score 0):

After some more work I changed the BEGIN quotation marks to double, and all the internal arguments to single, and that seems to have solved the issue.